# Listar resultados com jquery/php

Tags: jquery

Estou querendo listar resultados de uma página PHP usando jquery, do qual é atualizado a cada 3 segundos, mas não estou conseguindo. O código que estou usando é:

```
<div id="listar"></div>

<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>       

<script type="text/javascript">
function mostrar(){  
    $(document).ready(function(){       
             $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'atualizar.php',
                    success: function(dados){
                    $('#listar').append(dados[0]);                         
                    }
            });
    });
}
//setInterval(function(){ mostrar; }, 3000);
setInterval(mostrar, 3000);
</script>
```

Como forma de exemplo, coloquei o código PHP abaixo:

```
$ver = "teste";
echo json_decode($ver);
```

O problema está no Jquery e não no PHP ;)

Comment: O que está acontecendo de errado?

Comment: Não aparece o resultado do PHP.

Comment: Incluí no post um trecho que acabei esquecendo

Comment: Faz dentro do success `console.log(dados)`, e vê se está vindo algum resultado...

Comment: Não seria `json_encode` que você deveria estar utilizando?

Comment: Qual o status da requisição, 200, 500? Você só tem o callback de sucesso, coloque o de erro tambem, ele pode estar tendo problemas para fazer parse..

Comment: Realmente troquei para json_encode e funcionou. Me desculpem pela falta de atenção e obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O tipo de resposta na requisição `ajax` está pedindo por um objeto `json`, porém o código em php está fazendo o contrário: codificando um json para um objeto através do `json_decode`.

A [correção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263215/listar-resultados-com-jquery-php#comment539704_263215) foi trocar o método por `json_encode`.

```
$ver = "teste";
echo json_encode($ver); // codifica a variável para json e retorna via echo
```